# Parse date time with time offset in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, parsing, datetime, utc

I have dates in a following form (text):
`2016-07-05T13:09:35-06:00`

It's ODBC format, so I was able to simply:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DateTime2, REPLACE(LEFT(TimeModifiedUnparsed, 19), 'T', ' '), 120)
```

That get's me `DateTime2`, but without time offset.
I can parse and convert Hour and Minute and Sign out of last 6 characters and then do `DATEADD..` but I thought maybe there is a better way to convert such a strings to utc DateTime in SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select convert(datetime2, cast('2016-07-05T13:09:35-06:00' as datetimeoffset), 1)
```

Result:

```
2016-07-05 19:09:35.0000000
```