# How do I convert this "28 June 2021 10:52:16 CDT (GMT-0500)" to 06/28/2021

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have imported a flat file with a varchar field with data like this: "28 June 2021 10:52:16 CDT (GMT-0500)"

I need to convert this to a DateTime field so I can filter by date.  Help

Comment: Using `substring()`, convert that string to the [standard form of `datetimeoffset`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38251576/11683), then cast to it.

Answer (score 1):

See if this works for you - removing the unecessary timezone characters, formatting the offset correctly and then casting to `datetimeoffset`:

```
declare @date varchar(100)='28 June 2021 10:52:16 CDT (GMT-0500)'

select Cast(Replace(Reverse(Stuff(Stuff(Reverse(@date),7,8,''),4,0,':')),')','') as datetimeoffset)
```